# React component is never updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It feels very weird, but I am creating a new `React` component in my app in a fully analogous way to how I did it before with the other components and it is just not updating at all. The components' lifecycle methods are not called at all.

I have topmost `ControlledTabs` component which renders `SingleDatasetDashboard` which looks the following way:

```
class SingleDatasetDashboard extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);

}

render() {
return (
<div>
    {
      this.props.page === this.props.pageNames[1] ?
      <div>
        <MarkerGenesChart mainData={this.props.mainData} clusterIds={this.props.clusterIds} page = {this.props.page}
          allGenesData={this.props.allGenesData} datasetName = {this.props.datasetName} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
      </div>
      : ""
    }
    {
      this.props.page === this.props.pageNames[2] ?
      <div>
        <ClustersMultiChart mainData = {this.props.mainData} datasetName = {this.props.datasetName}
          page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
      </div>
      : ""
    }
    <div style={{visibility: this.props.page === this.props.pageNames[0] ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
      <ScatterChart key="main" datum = {this.props.mainData} type = "main" datasetName = {this.props.datasetName}
        page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
    </div>
</div>)
}
}

module.exports = SingleDatasetDashboard;
```

Here `MarkerGenesChart` and its child `ScatterChart` render perfectly well. Another `ScatterChart` at the very bottom is rendering fine too. Inside `ClustersMultiChart` I am having the folowing code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Row';
import ScatterChart from './ScatterChart';

class ClustersMultiChart extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

 }

 render() {
   return (
  this.props.mainData.map((clusterObj, idx) => {
      return <Col xs={4} md={4} key={"cluster" + idx + "chart"} >
        Hello! I am No {idx}
        <ScatterChart datum = {this.props.mainData}
          type = "cluster" datasetName = {this.props.datasetName}
          page = {this.props.page} pageNames = {this.props.pageNames}/>
    </Col>
      })
  )
  }
}

 module.exports = ClustersMultiChart;
```

There is also a child `ScatterChart` as in `MarkerGenesChart`. However, here the issue comes: `ScatterChart` only produces single `svg` tag and it  is never updated at all. Its `render()` has:

```
       <Col xs={5} md={5}>
                  <svg ref={node => this.node = node} width={1000} height={1000}></svg>
       </Col>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

If I remove `{ this.props.page === this.props.pageNames[2] ?` from `SingleDatasetDashboard`, it renders perfectly. However, I need to leave it there somehow, and it is working for `MarkerGenesChart` for some reason. I checked whether the page is switched correctly and it is.

> Update

This is definitely not related to `ScatterChart` component. Deleting it completely from `ClustersMultiChart` does not fix the absence of updates in it. Interesting thing is that `render()` is called but nothing else. Main data object `datum` is also passed since I am able to iterate over it.

> Update

Calling `setState()` in the topmost component after switching the page triggers the lifecycle methods of the `ClustersMutltiChart`. Here is how I am triggering the change of the page and the timeout function fixes the issue by calling the `setState()` after some time:

```
showNextPage = (pageNum) => {
const pageIdx = pageNum - 1;
const page = pageNames[pageIdx];
  this.setState({
    page: page
  });
  setTimeout(function() { //Start the timer
    this.setState({
      datasetName: this.state.datasetName
    })
  }.bind(this), 3000);
 }
```

Obviously I want it to happen without such forced update after some time. Just calling `this.forceUpdate()` without `setTimeout` does not fix the issue.

Comment: are you using setState at all for data changes?

Comment: For this one no. Only properties are passed from the top parent

Comment: Properties are changing, so I expect `componentWillReceiveProps()` to be called

Comment: Can you update the code of the parent , who is changing the property ?

Comment: Any of the component that you have added contains componentWllReceiveProps method. Moreover you are directly using props isstead of state. So I dont expect you need componentWllReceiveProps  either.

Comment: @AshokMandal No, its methods are not called either, so I guess the problem is with `ClustersMultiChart` only

Comment: Can you please add ScatterChart  component ? check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-es5vdl and give us a more input to help you out

Comment: `ScatterChart` is huge, `600 ` lines. The issue seems to lie outside of its code though, no? See the update above.

Comment: Your first `ScatterChart` has the props `key="main"`, but the ones in `ClustersMultiChart` is not having any `key`, is that the reason?

Comment: I am not using key inside of it. I just added it to remove Reacts’ complaint about all of the elements having individual key.

Comment: I do not understand why no lifecycle methods of the ClustersMultiChart are called. You think it can be because of errors in the ScatterChart still? There are no errors in the console, so I am very baffled at what is going on.

Comment: Would you be able to create a working example so we could investigate ?

Comment: Take the code above for `SingleDatasetDashboard` and try making it to work with multiple {this.props.page === pageNames[idx] ? ... : ""}. It really stops calling lifecycle methods of the child elements as long as we have more than one such `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it to work in an acceptable for me way. Just calling `this.forceUpdate()` in `componentDidMount` of `ClustersMutltiChart` made it to work:

`ClustersMutltiChart.jsx`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```